# getchar and scanf not works properly in c

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I'm having an issue in the following code:

```
    int main()
{
    char choice;
    char secondChoice;
    int howMany = 0;

    printf("WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO ORDER?\n F- fruitShake\n M- milkShake\n");
    choice = getchar();
    printf("WHAT SIZE?\n B-big\nS-small\n");
    secondChoice = getchar();
    printf("how many would you like?\n (choose a number between 1-9)\n");
    scanf("%d", &howMany);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

After entering the first `char` (of the what would you like to order) which works properly and right after that both of the `printf` shows up and it's not working well. (like its skipping on the `secondChoice = getchar();`)

Comment: You typed `F<RETURN>` (two chars), so you have the first `getchar()` reading `F` and the second reading  `<RETURN>`... Don't use `getchar` this way, or at least don't mix `getchar` and `scanf`...

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's not skipping but probably reading the newline character from your previous input(if you used the Enter key to terminate your input).

Answer (score 0):

Please run the modified code added below and observe that program works properly with addition of 2 statements.

```
  fflush(stdout);
  fflush(stdin);
```

Take note while using **fflush (stdin)** as some sources that i referred to advise not to use it. You may try removing the fflush(stdin) statement and notice the difference in your output

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    char secondChoice;
    int howMany = 0;

    printf("WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO ORDER?\n F- fruitShake\n M- milkShake\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    choice = getchar();
    fflush(stdout);fflush(stdin);

    printf("WHAT SIZE?\n B-big\n S-small\n");
    fflush(stdout);fflush(stdin);
    secondChoice = getchar();

    printf("how many would you like?\n (choose a number between 1-9)\n");
    fflush(stdout);fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &howMany);

    printf("\nChoice = %c\nsecondChoice = %c \nhowMany = %d\n\n", choice, secondChoice, howMany);
    fflush(stdout);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```